# MMQGIS Plugin dropdown/icon not appear (QGIS 3.4)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mmqgis

I am on the latest LTR for QGIS (3.4) and have installed the MMQGIS plugin. In the older version of QGIS (2.18) this caused a dropdown menu to appear on the top menu bar. However, there is no dropdown menu or icon in QGIS 3.4 in order to access the plugin features. I cannot figure out how to access the MMQGIS plugin short of going into the python repository for it. Any suggestions on how to manually add a link to the plugin or address the issue?

[image: Snap shot showing main menu bar in QGIS 2.18 with MMQGIS dropdown menu circled in red to illustrate what I expected to see]

Answer (score 1):

To activate the MMQGIS plugin (assuming it is already installed):

**1) Select *Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...***

**2) Click *Installed* on the left side of the plugin menu**

**3) Check the box next to *mmqgis***

[image]

MMQGIS should now be visible in the menu bar

[image]

*Screen shots from QGIS 3.8.3*

Comment: I checked and mmqgis was already activated. However, it appears that closing QGIS and rebooting my computer fixed the issue. I appreciate the response. This issue has been resolved.